# How to make a image file of Galaxy Note

Tags: 14.04, samsung, disk-image

I have a old Galaxy Note 1 - SHV-E160S which is connected to Ubuntu 14.04 PC with USB.

```
> Galaxy Note Information :
>  - Model : SHV-E160S
>  - OS : Android 4.0.4
>  - Kernel : 3.0.8-966809
```

I'm going to make a image file of Galaxy Note to my Ubuntu PC. My googling result was

```
dd if=/dev/sdc | tee mnt/sdc.img | md5sum >mnt/sdc.img.md5
```

is it right command ?

**Updates:**

I'm going to add more system mount point.

```
root@changjurhee-E300-AP55K:/home/changjurhee# cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=887536k,nr_inodes=213751,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=180320k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 rw,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sr0 /media/changjurhee/CAN\040Praise\0406 udf ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/changjurhee/LG\040External\040HDD fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
root@changjurhee-E300-AP55K:/home/changjurhee#
```

Comment: Do you understand that the only thing you can achieve is to create an image of emulated mass driver (if your phone even does such emulation, because Note2 does not for sure), this image will only contain user files  and you will even not be able to write it back because emulation software will not accept it? I suspect you do not realise what you want. Phone is in no way the USB thumb drive even if it tries to mimic it.

Comment: If you are running `dd` on the phone root console, then explai what Ubuntu has to do with it. And you will still end up with broken image.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the right command.

Check system mount point.

Check sdcard mount point.

This command creates a image of system dir.

`dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p9 of=/storage/sdcard0/system.img | md5sum > storage/sdcard0/system.img.md5`

and why are adding an md5sum to header of an img file? (<- Though this part is fine enough)